# What's the icon of Mathematica 11?

Tags: user-interface, version-11

Mathematica 11 trial has been released now, and I'm eager to know what's the icon of it as Mathematica's icon is always interesting.

I can only get access to Web Mathematica platform and I cannot download a new version yet, so I would like to have a way to find out the icon by inputting some code into Mathematica.

Are there any way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I assume it's the one on the [Mathematica web page](http://wolfram.com/mathematica/).

Comment: The fact that you did not find a valid tag for this question makes me wonder if it's off topic.  Perhaps you can improve the question to make it more clearly about *how to use the software.*

Comment: I'm just wondering how to get the icon from executing some code from Mathematica or Web-Mathematica. It's about how to use the software I suppose?

Comment: [`Import[FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Resources", "Mathematica.icns"}]]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TePEd.png)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I got nothing from this piece of code......

Comment: on windows: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAk2T.png)

Comment: I used a Mac. Maybe it's system dependent....

Comment: @MichaelE2 I see~

Comment: @Nasser My Mathematica versions 11 &12 seem to have the same icons. How can I apply  "!Mathematica graphics " in windows?  Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I really do not know. sorry.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you, my mistake. I thought it's possible to evaluate  the command " !Mathematica graphics" from your comment .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the `Resource` folder is not available in the cloud installation directory, which should contain the icon. But here is the icon from my installation.
[image]

Comment: I prefer the 'more 3D' style of previous versions. This looks like something trying to emulate an iOS icon: flat and flat.

Comment: @Wjx The 3D version showed on the official site seems to be only available on windows start up screen.